# How to specify server path in code?

Tags: wp-config

I am attempting to get the ACE editor to display wp-config.php for editing within the admin area (writing a plugin to do this). I assume I need to specify the server path for file_get_contents() but it’s not working. Also, specifying the server path to the editor, as currently I am using the url. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $s = file_get_contents('var/www/html/wp-config.php');
?>
<div id="editor"></div>
<script src="https://sketchwhatyousee.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-config-editor/ace/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var s = '<?= $s ?>';
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/php");
    editor.session.setValue(s);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Editing config files in the browser doesn't seem like a good idea to me, but the path to WordPress's installation directory should be available to you as the constant `ABSPATH`.

Comment: Thank you! It’s no different than opening  another app to ftp into the site, download the file and edit, then upload. All just to turn on/off debug. The plugin just makes it convenient without leaving WordPress. Only accessible to admin user.

Comment: Just be careful you don't make any errors when editing; if you drop a `;` or forget to close `"` you can render your site unreachable.

Comment: Yep! Learned that a long time ago lol! Thanks for the reminder though. I appreciate it!